# Call Velocity Macro by Name

Tags: velocity

is it somehow possible to call a velocity macro by name e.g.:

```
#macro (sayHello)
 Hello!
#end

#set ($macroName = "sayHello")

#$macroName()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
#set( $call = "#${macroname}()" )
#evaluate($call)
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick scan of the [docs](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.5/user-guide.html#velocimacros) does not indicate support for this.  But you could do something like the following:

```
#macro(myMacro1 $param1 $param2)
    ## stuff here...
#end

#macro(myMacro2 $param1 $param2)
    ## stuff here...
#end

#if($condition)
    #myMacro1
#else
    #myMacro2
#end
```

Or maybe your macro needs to take in additional parameters to account for all scenarios.

Comment: Thats what I wanted to avoid. I need something generic.